# Showing message Twig_Error_Loader in open cart v3

Tags: php, xml, opencv3.0

I want to activate it after installing an extension, but I get this error.

> Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/admin/controller/extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.php
>   on line 142Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/admin/controller/extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.php
>   on line 146Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/admin/controller/extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.php
>   on line 150Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/admin/controller/extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.php
>   on line 153Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
>   /var/www/web1"""43509/html/opencart/admin/controller/extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.php
>   on line 154 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with
>   message 'Unable to find template "extension/feed/gcrdev_sitemap.twig"
>   (looked into: /var/www/"""/html/opencart/admin/view/template).' in
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/"""/html/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(139):
>   Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('extension/feed/...') #1
>   /var/www/""""/html/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(312):
>   Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('extension/feed/...') #2
>   /var/www/""""/html/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(378):
>   Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('extension/feed/...', NULL) #3
>   /var/www/"""""/html/opencart/system/store/modification/system/library/template/twig.php(42):
>   Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('extension/feed/...') #4
>   /var/www/""""/html/opencart/system/library/template.php(51):
>   Template\Twig->render('extension/feed/...', '1') #5 /var/www/web143 in
>   /var/""""/html/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
>   on line 215

Answer (score 0):

That module could not find it's template file. 
follow these steps below to fix your problems.

First create your `module`

2.And you must MAP your corresponding module template.(html file)

3.After successfully create your module you must run the composer.  `composer -o dump-autoload`

Comment: ı dont understand

Comment: If you're not a developer, don't use StackOverflow, you should use the OpenCart support forum instead: https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=190